# Question about an isomorphism result in homotopy theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, winding-number

I have another question regarding homotopy theory and winding numbers (or degrees).

In Manton and Sutcliffe they state the following theorem:

$\pi_2(G/H)=\pi_1(H)$

provided $G$ is a compact, connected and simply connected group, and $H$ denotes the subgroup of $G$. They don't really elaborated about what this theorem exactly entails and my question is:

Does this theorem means that the winding number of the R.H.S. is equal to the winding number of the L.H.S.?

In the beginning I understood this theorem as implying that the winding number belongs to the same group, but they are not necessary equal to each other. I.e. if the winding number is, for example, always an integer for the R.H.S., then it must also be an integer for the L.H.S. But looking at how they use this theorem later in the book, it seems that the winding numbers must also equal each other. Could anybody confirm this for me?

Thanks in advance,

Hunter

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the winding number of a group.  For me, winding numbers are a property of a closed curve $\gamma$ and a point $p$, so that one can speak of the winding number of $\gamma$ about $p$.  What do you mean by the winding number of the RHS ($\pi_1(H)$) or the LHS ($\pi_2(G/H)$ of your equation?

Comment: Consider a map: $\Omega: S^1 \mapsto S^1$. Then the winding number is the amount of times the map covers the target circle, when it goes around the domain circle once. The case I'm particularly interested in is when there is a map from $S^2$ to $\mathrm{SU(2)/U(1)}$ and I would like to relate that topology to the map of the equatator at $S^2$, which is of course just a circle, to $\mathrm{U(1)}$. I think my explanation might be a bit confusing, but hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Given a map from $S^2$ to $SU(2)/U(1)$, first deform it so that it maps all of the southern hemisphere (including the equator) to the base point. Its restriction to the northern hemisphere (also including the equator) can be lifted to $SU(2)$ (because the hemisphere is contractible). Since the equator mapped to the base point of $SU(2)/U(1)$, the lifted map will send the equator into $U(1)$.

Comment: Conversely, given a map of the circle $S^1$ into $U(1)\subseteq SU(2)$, use the fact that $SU(2)$ is simply connected to extend your map to send a disk $D$ spanning $S^1$ into $SU(2)$.  Projecting that into $SU(2)/U(1)$, you get a map of $D$ into $SU(2)/U(1)$ sending the boundary $S^1$ of $D$ to the base point; so it amounts to a map of $D/S^1\cong S^2$ into $SU(2)/U(1)$. Thwo exercises for you: (1) Check that this construction and the one in my previous comment are inverses of each other up to homotopy. (2) Check that all this is the same as the fibration exact-sequence argument.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Andreas Blass, I didn't realise you answered to me. Your answer is very mathematical, and unfortunately I'm not, so I don't really understand you. The way I understand isomorphisms is via group theory, where it (roughly) means that an isomorphism between two groups (eg $\mathrm{U(1)}$ and $\mathrm{SO(2)}$ have the same multiplication structure and are locally the same, however globally they are different. I have the feeling that in the case of my post it means something else, but I'm not sure what it means. I think that it that it means that the degree of the......

Comment: .... $\pi_2(\mathrm{SU(2)}/\mathrm{U(1)})$ is equal to the degree of the $\pi_1(\mathrm{U(1)})$, but I'm not sure. In other words, if a map from $S^2$ to $\mathrm{SU(2)}/\mathrm{U(1)}$ has a degree of $3$ (for example), then the map from $S^1$ to $\mathrm{U(1)}$ also has a degree of $3$?